# Constraint Layout - Guideline set orientation programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to set Guideline's orientation programmatically from the new ConstraintLayout?

I'm using this version of ConstraintLayout library:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

If you decompile the ConstraintLayout class, you can see that LayoutParams has field "orientation", but it's not a public field and there's no setter method for that.

Comment: Can you tell me that which dependency you have added for Constraint Layout?

Comment: @KishuDroid I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update to ConstraintLayout alpha 6 -- the orientation field has been made public.

Answer (score 6):

With current version of the library, in code, you can set guideline's orientation using constraintset.

```
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);


    constraintSet.create(R.id.guideline, ConstraintSet.VERTICAL_GUIDELINE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change **app:orientation** to **android:orientation**

> Changed orientation attribute namespace from app to android to fix a
>   conflict with GridLayout

Available At [RecentLogs](http://tools.android.com/recent).

You can't edit the **Guideline class manually** as it uses **java.awt.Rectangle** and **java.awt libraries** which are not available in Android.

*So I guess programatically it is not possible but you can do it via XML.*

I hope it will give you some clues on it or if you have still issue with that then you can post your issue at [Google Code Issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).